# how to prevent allowing null values in a table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a program that has 11 variable that need to be inserted into a SQL 2008 Express DB. All works until the variables that can be NULL are NULL. Then the SQL does not get the data. Here is my code and appreciate all that can help:

```
 private void PostDatatoServer()
       {
           String connectionString = @"Data Source=LUCKYTIGER\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=John;Integrated Security=True";
           SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
           con.Open();
           textBox1.Text = "Connection made";
           SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
           string str = "";
           str += "INSERT INTO Parsed(Date, Gal, Sys, Sl, ST, PN, PlayN, Sym, Rk, All, Rel)";
           str += "VALUES(@Date, @Gal, @Sys, @Sl, @ST, @PN, @PlayN, @Sym, @Rk, @All, @Rel)";
           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
           cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
           cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Date", uegParser.strTime));
           cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Gal", Convert.ToInt16(uegParser.strGalaxyNum)));
           cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Sys", Convert.ToInt16(uegParser.strSystemNum)));
           cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Sl", uegParser.intSlot));
           cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ST", uegParser.intSlotType));
           if (uegParser.strPlanetName == "")
               cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PN", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DBNull.Value);
           else
               cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PN", uegParser.strPlanetName));
           if (uegParser.strPlayerName == "")
           {
               cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PlayN", DBNull.Value));
               TextBox2.Text = "Null player name";
           }
           else
           {
               cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PlayN", uegParser.strPlayerName));
           }
           if (uegParser.strSymbols == "")
               cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Sys", DBNull.Value));
           else
               cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Sym", uegParser.strSymbols));
           if (uegParser.strRank == "")
               cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Rk", DBNull.Value));
           else
               cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Rk", uegParser.strRank));
           if (uegParser.strAlliance == "")
               cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@All", DBNull.Value));
           else
               cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@All", uegParser.strAlliance));
           cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Rel", uegParser.intRelationship));

           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
           con.Close();
           TextBox2.Text = "Connection closed";
       }
```

Comment: What do you want to do if a null value occurs? Prevent the insert? Insert a default value?

Comment: Declare the columns as `NOT NULL` or add a `NOT NULL` constraint.

Comment: 1 major thing:  Use parameters to prevent sql-injection!....

Comment: What do you want to do when you encounter a NULL? Should it not insert that row? Should it insert some kind of default value?

Comment: I'm not fully understanding what you want to have happen, but if you want to substitute another value for the null at the point of insertion, you may find the NULL COALESCE feature useful.

Comment: So add an if condition before you insert? Honestly I would think you could this whole process in one step instead of reading in the excel spreadsheet in one event, storing the dataset in the session and then inserting it row by agonizing row. I would just create a connection directly to your spreadsheet and do the insert as one statement.

Comment: Simple check for null - if (id == null)   and don't open and close the connection (twice) in the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reconsider how you read your data from spreadsheet. Apparently you put the whole sheet into one big `DataTable` and then iterate over this. You should split your datareading, such that you only read the first two columns into one `DataTable` and the remaining five columns into a second `DataTable`. Then iterate over the two DataTables separately and save the contained rows into database.

If you really just want to prohibit to create rows with null values, you could simply check your values for null before you do the insert.

```
 if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Id) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Name)) {
    cmd = new SqlCommand( ....);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }
```

Additionally some hints:

1. Take a look at parametrized and prepared queries, they make your code a lot more secure.
2. You do not need to open and close your sql connection for every single command. You can open it before your loop, create and execute some commands, and close it after the loop, when your are finished.
3. You are missing the first row of your data. The vast majority of collections in c# start at index 0.

EDIT

For your request, I added the null checks into your code. **But I really don't think you should do it this way!** Like I mentionioned above, you should split your datatable into two tables, such that each of them only contains the relevant rows. And you should have a look at Igor's answer on how to create parameterized queries! And take into account the other hints from above. And finally, I don't mean to be rude, but you really should grab a good book or some tutorials from the web and learn the basics, so you will be able to understand the anwswers to your question.

```
protected void btn_insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds = (DataSet)Session["DTset"];

        for (int i = 1; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            string Id = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString();
            string Name = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString();

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connStr);
            SqlCommand cmd;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Id) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name)) {
                cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tbl1(ID,Name) values ('" + Id + "','" + Name + "')", con);
                con.Open();
                int j= cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }

            string Id1 = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString();
            string Name1 = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][3].ToString();
            string VehicleTypeId = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][4].ToString();
            string VehicleType = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][5].ToString();
            string Capacity = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][6].ToString();


            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Id1) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name1) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(VehicleTypeId) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(VehicleType) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Capacity)) {
                string InsQuery = "insert into tbl2(Id,Name,Subject,status,review) values ('" + Id1 + "','" + Name1 + "','" + Subject+ "','" + status+ "','" + review+ "')";
                cmd = new SqlCommand(InsQuery,con);
                con.Open();
                int k=  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can see how to create parametrized queries in @Igor's answer

Comment: Just check each parameter you use in the first query for null then execute the first query. Do the same for the values for the second query and the if these values are not null, execute the second query,

Answer (score 2):

**The following is not an answer to your question** but an example of all the places your code is abusing Ado.Net. Try to restructure any ado.net code you have in this manner. I do agree with the comments, your general approach is probably wrong however these are general pointers that you could probably benefit from in the rest of your code. Pointers are.

- Always wrap SqlConnections in using blocks
- Always use parameterized queries

  - Always specify the parameter SqlDbType (*when using SqlServer obviously*)
  - Always use the correct parameter types instead of adding string values

*Refactored ado.net code*

```
protected void btn_insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    // i would not use Session unless necessary but that is out of scope for the question
    // also do not forget to dispose the datatabale when finished and remove it from the session
    ds = (DataSet)Session["DTset"];


    // always wrap your SqlConnection in a using block
    // it ensures the connection is always released
    // also there is no reason to have this inside the loop
    // there is no reason to close/reopen it every time
    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connStr))
    {
        con.Open(); // open once
        for (int i = 1; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            // do not convert everything to strings, pick the correct type as it is in the table or convert it to the correct type if the table contains only strings
            string Id = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString();
            string Name = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString();

            cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tbl1(ID,Name) values (@ID,@Name)";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Id).SqlDbType = SqlDbType.; // pick the correct dbtype
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Name).SqlDbType = SqlDbType.; // pick the correct dbtype
            int j= cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            // do not convert everything to strings, pick the correct type as it is in the table or convert it to the correct type if the table contains only strings
            string Id1 = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString();
            string Name1 = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][3].ToString();
            string VehicleTypeId = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][4].ToString();
            string VehicleType = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][5].ToString();
            string Capacity = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][6].ToString();

            string InsQuery = "insert into tbl2(Id,Name,Subject,status,review) values (@Id,@Name,@Subject,@status,@review)";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(InsQuery,con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Id1).SqlDbType = SqlDbType.; // pick the correct dbtype
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name1).SqlDbType = SqlDbType.; // pick the correct dbtype
            // add the rest of your parameters here

            int k=  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @user6429940 - it is the data type for the column that you are assigning the value to. Its an enumeration, you just have to complete it using the correct value like `Int` or `BigInt` or `Varchar` etc.

Comment: @user6429940 - here is the example for `id`, based on this I really hope you can figure the rest of them out: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Id).SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;` (notice I added `Int`). For a list of all possible enumeration values see [SqlDbType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @user6429940 - did you look at the enumeration? The length for varXXX (like varchar) is another property on the `SqlParameter` and can not be set using `AddWithValue` but you probably do not need it.

Comment: @user6429940 this is not a programming service

Answer (score 0):

Fool-proof solution: use SQL Stored procedure.

```
--sql
create procedure dbo.Parsed_i
   @Date datetime,
   @Gal int,
   --so on
   @PN nvarchar(100) = null --default value
   --so on
as
INSERT INTO Parsed(Date, Gal, Sys, Sl, ST, PN, PlayN, Sym, Rk, All, Rel)
VALUES(@Date, @Gal, @Sys, @Sl, @ST, @PN, @PlayN, @Sym, @Rk, @All, @Rel)

//C#
//...
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.Parsed_i", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ST", SqlDbType.Int).Value = uegParser.intSlotType;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(uegParser.strPlanetName))
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@PN",  SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = uegParser.strPlanetName;
//note: no **else** part
//so on
```